# How can I factorize a panGestureHandling Function in Swift for UILabel and UIImageView types?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, refactoring, uilabel

I building a photo collage app and have UILabel and UIImageView elements that I would like to add Gesture Recognizers to. Currently, I am handling the PanGestures for each type in two different functions since I need to declare the type of the panGesture.view as either UILabel or UIImageView:

```
func handlePanGesture(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {
// Get translation
var translation = panGesture.translationInView(view)
panGesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
panGesture.delegate = self

// Add dx,dy to current image position
var image = panGesture.view as! UIImageView
image.center = CGPoint(x: image.center.x + translation.x, y: image.center.y + translation.y)

}

func handlePanGestureText(panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {
var translation = panGesture.translationInView(view)
panGesture.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
panGesture.delegate = self

var label = panGesture.view as! UILabel
label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x + translation.x, y: label.center.y + translation.y)
}
```

Is it possible to factorize this code and put it all in one function and use it for both types? (e.g. if UIPanGestureRecognizer = UILabel {
...}

Best,

Max

Answer (score 0):

Here sample code from Apple :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Touches/Listings/Touches_GestureRecognizers_Touches_APLAppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435-Touches_GestureRecognizers_Touches_APLAppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_6